# Can not connect with PowerShell remote session with SSL, certificate is invalid

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to connect to my Azure Windows 2019 Server with PowerShell 7 from my desktop computer using the following line:

```
 New-PSSession -ComputerName myserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -UseSSL -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop
```

getting the following error message:

```
 The server certificate on the destination computer (myserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:5986) has the following errors:    
 The SSL certificate is signed by an unknown certificate authority.   
 The SSL certificate is expired.
```

(I do not know if it has something diagnostic value: When I try to connect with remote desktop to the same computer, it asked me if I trust, I answered yes, and checked do not ask again, so now it works (remote desktop) and not asking, just connecting.)

**Question**

How can I diagnose this PowerShell remote session error further?

Comment: TLS (which is now used in place of SSL) the Server sends a certificate block with names of acceptable certificates and the client looks for one in the stores.  The error message indicates the certificate that is bein used has expired.  In your browser option you can see a list of certificates and the expiration dates.  "unknown certificate authority' may or may not prevent the connection.  It depends on your network settings.